# SwiftUI tvOS Button - Parallax?

Tags: button, swiftui, parallax, tvos

Working with the landmark-Sample code from Apple.
I got my app running like this:
https://youtu.be/CLL_oknQEDI?t=1118

However, how is it possible to achieve the "parallax"-effect on the buttons/navigationLinks?

If you are on the focused button, you can't wiggle it. Like on all other AppleTV buttons in store etc. Didn't find any modifier to do so on Buttons or Navigationlinks.
All i found is this forum post: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/124684

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Button(action: {
            print("Tapped item")
        }) {
            landmark.image
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 255, height: 155)
                .cornerRadius(5)
            Text(landmark.name)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                .font(.caption)
        }

}
```